# Initial (default) value on Django ChoiceFilter select box

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I am trying to set **initial, default** value on select box created by DjangoFilter **ChoiceFilter** (more info [here](http://django-filter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/filters.html)). Code seems to be pretty simple:

```
class MyFilter(FilterSet):
    CHOICES = (
        ('', 'Any'),
        ('closed', 'Closed'),
        ('new', 'New'),
    )

    my_select_box = ChoiceFilter(choices=CHOICES, initial='new')

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ('my_select_box')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyFilter, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.form.helper = FormHelper()
        self.form.helper.form_method = 'get'
        self.form.helper.add_input(Submit('submit', 'Search'))
        self.form.helper.form_class = 'form-inline'
        self.form.helper.field_class = 'm-r m-b-sm'
        self.form.helper.label_class = 'm-r'
```

On views.py:

```
class MyView(BaseListView):
    content_template = "template.html"
    model = MyModel
    filter_class = MyFilter
    table_class = MyTable

class BaseListView(BaseView, MultipleObjectMixin, SingleTableMixin):
    table_class = None
    filter_class = None
    queryset = None
    list = None
    dictionary = {}

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        if self.list is not None:
            self.object_list = self.list
        else:
            if self.queryset is None:
                self.queryset = self.get_queryset()
            self.object_list = self.queryset

        if self.filter_class is not None:
            filter = self.filter_class(self.request.GET, queryset=self.object_list)
            table = self.table_class(filter.qs)
            # filter.form.fields['my_select_box'].default = 'new'
            # filter.form.initial['my_select_box'] = 'new'
            ids = json.dumps(list(filter.qs.values_list('id', flat=True)))
        else:
            filter = ""
            table = self.table_class(self.object_list)
            ids = [obj['id'] for obj in self.object_list] if self.object_list is list else None

        RequestConfig(self.request, paginate={"per_page": 10}).configure(table)
        kwargs['content'] = render_to_string(self.content_template, context_instance=RequestContext(self.request),
                                             dictionary=dict(
                                                 {'filter': filter, 'object_list': self.object_list, 'ids_list': ids,
                                                  'table': table}.items() + self.dictionary.items()))
        context = super(BaseListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        return context
```

On template.html:

```
<div class="panel-body">
        <section class="panel panel-default">
            <header class="panel-heading font-bold">
                Filter
            </header>
            <div class="panel-body">
                {% crispy filter.form %}
            </div>
        </section>
    {% render_table table %}
</div>
```

On template side I can see with debugger that form.my_select_box.initial is set to be 'new'. But well, its not working (instead of `'new'` I was trying also integers). If I change `CHOICES` to be like this:

```
CHOICES = (
    ('any', 'Any'),
    ('closed', 'Closed'),
    ('', 'New'),
)
```

It seems to work - but I don't have value from "New" selection, which makes things rough later - I can of course swap my `''` value to become `'new'`, and `'any'` to become `''` on the backend in views.py by editing request.GET (not pretty solution though), but after page refresh if I used **New**, I see results for **New**, but selections displays **Any** (and opposite).

I believe solution can be achieved on server side (I don't want JS)?

Comment: Show the code of your view, please.

Comment: I've already noticed that error comes from this line: self.filter_class(self.request.GET, queryset=self.object_list), if I delete first param, 'new' is selected as should (but now my filtering is simply not working).